# how to use @param in jsdoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I know this is a dumb question, but I just started working with jsdoc and I'm having issues trying to generate the doc file.

I've followed some examples I found online which all seem to be essentially the same, but for some reason I cannot generate the documentation for one of the variables I want to document.

this is my code.

```
/**
 *@fileOverview mainController ' main controller file'
 *@param Controller here
 */
 function (jQuery, Controller, JSONModel, Filter){
  .....
  }
```

The first part @fileOverview works the @param doesn't, the index.html file doesn't show any information about it and I see no errors.
I'm definitely doing something wrong here but I don't know what

Comment: Have you tried placing a hyphen between the parameter name and the description like so `@param Controller - here`?

Comment: that doesn't work, I tried just @param Controller before and that didn't work. Also, I noticed that '@fileOverview' gets shown in green as it being a comment whereas '@param' is shown in blue, I don't know if that matters. Do I need to include jsdoc in my dependencies or something?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/**
 * @fileOverview mainController ' main controller file'
 * @param {object} Controller here
 */
function (jQuery, Controller, JSONModel, Filter){
.....
}
```

(note the spacing changes)

Comment: that didn't work. The documentation seems straight forward and what I'm doing seems to be the way to do it

Comment: I guess I didn't understand the documentation but I tried the following and it seems to work
/**
 * '@fileOverview mainController' ' main controller file'
 * '@constructor' comments
*  '@param' {object} Controller here
 */
function (jQuery, Controller, JSONModel, Filter){
.....
}
then when I bring up index.html I can expand the function and see its parameters